# VBA Excel IF condition for splitting address columns

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to split my addresses into separate cells. My address is combined by commas and basically, the number of separate cells is comma-dependant.

I found and implemented a very good solution, which is under the following thread here:

[Split address field in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14759174/split-address-field-in-excel)

It works, but the primary condition is keeping the string with the same number of commas.

If for example, the address looks like this:

**1 - 40 Williams Court, 24-26 Poole Road, Bournemouth, BH4 9DT**

then it's fine (regarding my whole macro),

but when the address is shorter (including 2 instead of 3 commas in the whole string)

**12 Boyd Close, Coventry, CV2 2NF**

then in turn I am getting a mess like below:

[image]

So I need the if statement, which will allow me to distinguish the shorter and longer address strings.

I've prepared one column, where I defined the number of commas.

Regarding this I tried to implement the following code:

```
  Dim Wksht As Worksheet

  Dim MyArray() As String, myPath As String
  Dim lRow As Long, i As Long, j As Long, c As Long


  Set Wksht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Final")

  Set Wksht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Final")


  Sheets("Address").Application.Union(Columns("J"), Columns("P"), Columns("O")).Copy
  Wksht.Columns("A:B").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

  Wksht.Columns("A").ColumnWidth = 60
  Wksht.Columns("A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete

  Wksht.Columns("A:D").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, _
  CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove


  Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long
  With Wksht
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).row
  End With
  For i = 1 To LastRow
  If ActiveSheet.Range("U" & i) = 3 Then
   With Wksht
    lRow = .Range("E" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    For i = 1 To lRow
        If InStr(1, .Range("E" & i).Value, ",", vbTextCompare) Then
            MyArray = Split(.Range("E" & i).Value, ",")
            c = 1
            For j = 0 To UBound(MyArray)
                .Cells(i, c).Value = MyArray(j)
                c = c + 1
            Next j
        End If
    Next i
   End With
   End If
  Next i
```

There is no error at all. The debugger just shows:

```
       If InStr(1, .Range("E" & i).Value, ",", vbTextCompare) Then
```

but I don't understand, why am I receiving empty columns. Why this code is not executed at all?

I want these addresses split regarding the number of commas defined in the separate column.

[image]

**UPDATED:**

This approach also doesn't work

```
 For i = 1 To lLastRow
 If Wksht.Range("F" & i).Value = 2 Then
 Wksht.Range("C" & i).Value = Wksht.Range("D" & i).Value
 End If
 Next i
```

Comment: The code you have posted will not compile at all (nested `For i ...`)

Comment: So how to unnest For i...

Comment: Its hard to see the intent of your code, its not what your running because it does not run at all. If you just want the full address strings split into columns record and adapt a macro of the *Text to Columns* tool on the Data tab.

Comment: I don't think so, everything seems to be clear here

Comment: For a result, you show only that you want the zip code split off.  You can do that with a simple formula. Is that really what you want?

Comment: I need to have it automatized. What I've done now, I placed the comma before each shorter address. In this case, I could implement only one code without the condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Alex K. pointed out, this is a job that *Text to Columns* was designed for.  Please try the code below – it is based on the data layout off your second image (original data in column `E`) and on the sheet called `Final`.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Macro1()
Dim LastRow As Long, ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Final")
LastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row

Application.DisplayAlerts = False   '<~~ to stop the warning if data already exists at the destination

ws.Range("E1:E" & LastRow).TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1))

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

**EDIT**

If your aim is purely to separate the postcode from the rest of the address, you could achieve this based on the location of the *last* comma in the string (as opposed to the *number* of commas) using the in-built `InStrRev()` function.

The following code assumes the complete address is in column `E` and puts the address (minus the postcode) in column `A` - and puts the postcode (minus the rest of the address) in column `B`.  All on the sheet called `Final`.

```
Option Explicit
Sub SeparatePostCode()
Dim LastRow As Long, ws As Worksheet, c As Range, adr As String
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Final")
LastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row

'Get the address minus the postcode
For Each c In ws.Range("A1:A" & LastRow)
    adr = c.Offset(0, 4).Value
    c.Value = Mid(adr, 1, Len(adr) - (Len(adr) - InStrRev(adr, ",") + 1))
Next c

'Get the postcode minus the address
For Each c In ws.Range("B1:B" & LastRow)
    adr = c.Offset(0, 3).Value
    c.Value = Right(adr, (Len(adr) - InStrRev(adr, ",") - 1))
Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: Te code is fine, but what I wanted to achieve is to have address and postcode sorted in one column, unlike the screen I showed in the question. The column F includes a number of commas in each string. I wanted the condition-based text-to columns based on the column F. Is that possible?

Comment: Please see my **EDIT** above.

Comment: that's perfect! Thank you